# Expandable Divs/Paragraphs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am looking to create an help section for my website and wish to use expandable divs so that when you click on a link it opens up below the link and when you click a separate link it closes the previous one and opens the other one below it?

I'm using asp.net web forms and vb.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('yourdiv').style.display="none";
```

or to show it again:

```
document.getElementById('yourdiv').style.display="block";
```

More examples:  http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-Div-Collapse-Style-Using-Display-None.aspx